# Monitor apps accessing HDD

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, monitoring

I have SSD and HDD installed on my laptop. Ubuntu 14.10 x64 and all apps installed on SSD. But some apps are reading and/or writing data to/from HDD, so it makes OS freeze sometimes, since my HDD is slower.

How can I inspect **those apps** and **files they are accessing**? so that later I could find out why would they behave like that.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can also use lsof aka "List open files": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lsof

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is not really monitoring, but with this command you can list all running file accesses.

```
sudo find /proc -type d -name fd -exec sh -c "echo {}: && ls -l {}" \;
```

check the output if you find the path to your hdd there.

Comment: Thanks. But grepping '/home/me/media' from output of above command didn't return any results. Or it's not the way I should check it?

Comment: Then there is actually no access to your hdd.
You could try this tool for monitoring: https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify, you will see file accesses but no process id's.